# Unknown function saxon:parse-html when compiling stylesheet

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0, saxon-js

I am working on an XSL transformation on Oxygen using the Saxon-EE 10.3 transformer. I want to use the compiled stylesheet (sef.json) later on my website with Saxon-JS 2.
Inside of the XSL transformation I am using the saxon:parse-html function with the saxon namespace declared as following:

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:prop="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-property"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:style="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-style-property" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
    xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs prop ixsl js style saxon xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="3.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
```

and the function is called this way:

```xsl
          <xsl:call-template name="nameTemplate">
              <xsl:with-param name="html">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse-html(var)"></xsl:copy-of>
              </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
```

I tried to compile the stylesheet through this command:

```
xslt3 -xsl:test.xsl -export:test.sef.json -t
```

but I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to compile stylesheet: Static error in XPath on line 147 in Oxygen/Test.xsl {saxon:parse-html(?Text)}: Unknown function Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}parse-html()
Error Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors}XPST0017 at xpath.xsl#963
    Failed to compile stylesheet
Error Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors}XPST0017 at xpath.xsl#963
    Static error in XPath on line 147 in Oxygen/Test.xsl {saxon:parse-html(?Text)}: Unknown function Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}parse-html()
```

The transformation works without problem inside Oxygen though.

Comment: With oXygen, you use the Java version of Saxon, which in the PE and EE editions provides that extension function `saxon:parse-html`. With `xslt3` you use the JavaScript/Node.js version of Saxon, a different product, which, as far as I know, doesn't support that extension function. I don't know what happens if you try to compile with Saxon Java EE in oXygen and target JS. As for a workaround, if your aim is to parse a string of HTML inside XSLT, you could try to use the pure XSLT 2 HTML parser of David Carlisle or you could try to call into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I compiled it in oXygen with Saxon 10.3 and it did produce a sef.json output. However, when I tried to reuse it in the Javascript function `SaxonJS.transform({stylesheetLocation: "oxygenOutput.sef.json", …})`, there was the same kind of error: `Object { message: "Unknown function local name parse-html" ...}`. I will look up these other solutions if I cannot manage with parse-html.

Comment: Martin is correct (as always): the function is available in the Java product but not in the Javascript product. We still have a bit of work to do in managing such differences when compiling under Java for execution under Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to call into JavaScript e.g. set up a `script` element

```
<script>
function parseHTML(html) { return new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'); }
</script>
```

in your HTML document and then inside of XSLT with Saxon JS 2 in the browser you should be able to use e.g.

```
ixsl:window() => ixsl:get('parseHTML') => ixsl:apply([var])
```

instead of `saxon:parse-html(var)`, with a namespace declaration of `xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"` in your XSLT.

Another way to not require you to set up the script code in addition to the XSLT code is to use `ixsl:eval` to run the JavaScript directly from XSLT in Saxon-JS 2; I have set up an example at https://martin-honnen.github.io/saxon-js-parse-html-test/html/test-saxon-parse-html2.html which basically uses an implementation

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:function name="saxon:parse-html" as="document-node()" use-when="system-property('xsl:product-name') = 'Saxon-JS'">
    <xsl:param name="html" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="ixsl:eval('new DOMParser()') => ixsl:call('parseFromString', [$html, 'text/html'])"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

of the XSLT 3 module https://github.com/martin-honnen/saxon-js-parse-html-test/blob/master/xslt/override-saxon-parse-html2.xsl.

You can `xsl:import` that in your other XSLT code, as done in https://github.com/martin-honnen/saxon-js-parse-html-test/blob/master/xslt/test-override-saxon-parse.xsl with e.g. `<xsl:import href="override-saxon-parse-html2.xsl"/>` and call e.g. `saxon:parse-html(.)`.

I managed to compile that code to an SEF file with the settings `xslt3 -xsl:test-override-saxon-parse.xsl -nogo -export:test-override-saxon-parse. -sef.json -ns:"##html5"` and that way the HTML page https://martin-honnen.github.io/saxon-js-parse-html-test/html/test-saxon-parse-html2.html can simply run that XSLT with

```
           SaxonJS.transform({
                stylesheetLocation: '../xslt/test-override-saxon-parse.sef.json',
                sourceLocation: '../xml/sample2.xml',
                destination: 'appendToBody'
            }, 'async')
```

As an alternative, you could import the pure XSLT 2 HTML parser that David Carlisle has somewhere on GitHub into your XSLT code.